# Do you know where specifically I should generate this data for a Google Analytics API connection?

Tags: google-analytics

I am not familiar with the GA API, and a developer (he is not available at this time) is requesting the below data for a connection to my Google Analytics account.

Can you point me in the right direction to locate or generate this data?

1. Client ID
2. Client Secret
3. Token
4. Refresh Token

I thought the Token was generated after the connection, so it would not be something I provide.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Please read `Oauth2.0` documentation for the same. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Answer (score 2):

As dikesh has referenced, the developer site has tons of useful info.

To add on, here is a concise guide to get what you have asked.
 - Client ID and Client Secret 
     - visit google developer console (https://console.developers.google.com/home)
     - create a new project (look top right side)
     - enable Analytics API (search for "analtyics api" on overview page)
     - create credentials (look left hand side)
     - follow the appropriate steps to create your client and secret file (simple and straightforward)

- Token

  - you are absolutely correct, at least with the way I understand the concept and have implemented using service account. Essentially, after you request for a service object with a call such as `service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)`, an access token is granted under the name 'service'. And with this token, we can make management API calls. E.g.,  `account_summaries = service.management().accountSummaries().list().execute()`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have him check out this tutorial on how to use [Python to pull data from the Google Analytics API](http://www.ryanpraski.com/google-analytics-reporting-api-python-tutorial/). Step #4 describes and has a video on how to create a new Google Analytics API project in the developer console.